# Is there a way to specify an alternate scalastyle-config.xml under IntelliJ for test scope?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalastyle

In `build.sbt` you can specify an alternate scalastyle config file for test scope using this:

`(scalastyleConfig in Test) := baseDirectory.value / "scalastyle-test-config.xml"`

This is useful when you want to loosen the checks in `Test` scope.

Unfortunately, IntelliJ ignores this setting and looks for the file in it's default location.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible, the locations are hard-coded. I've created an issue for you:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12086